# Null Reference Type Error using Javascript in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013, nullreferenceexception

Having an issue with javascript in sharepoint 2013. We have set up javascript and it is working by changing the colours of the rows in a task list. The issue is when the user goes into quick edit, and then stops that edit, the script stops running and the colours are removed. This is the script.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
          OnPostRender: function(ctx) {
            var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
            for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
            {
              var high = rows[i]["Priority"] == "High";
              if (high)
              {
                var rowElementId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
                var tr = document.getElementById(rowElementId);
                tr.style.backgroundColor = "#F78181";
              }
            }
            for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
            {
              var normal = rows[i]["Priority"] == "Normal";
              if (normal)
              {
                var rowElementId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
                var tr = document.getElementById(rowElementId);
                tr.style.backgroundColor = "#BCF5A9";
              }
            }
            for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
            {
              var milestone = rows[i]["Priority"] == "Milestone";
              if (milestone)
              {
                var rowElementId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
                var tr = document.getElementById(rowElementId);
                tr.style.backgroundColor = "#F3F781";
              }
            }
            for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
            {
              var goLive = rows[i]["Priority"] == "Go Live";
              if (goLive)
              {
                var rowElementId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
                var tr = document.getElementById(rowElementId);
                tr.style.backgroundColor = "#81B1F8";
              }
            }
          }
        });
</script>
```

This is an image of what it looks like on page load.

[image]

(NOTE: Priority is in the table but have removed it from the screenshot as it had a users name on there)

This is when we are in quick edit mode...

[image]

and this is what happens when we stop editing.

[image]

I am trying to help someone who is working with sharepoint. This not a language I have ever used so don't really know how to solve the problem. What I have done is create some JS code that does a simple alert on post render. This did not cause any issues. However, the minute we try to deal with the table content the problem arises. At a guess I think that SharePoint is changing the ID and so the JS script is no longer pointing at the right object? Having said that I tried to write some javascript that didn't use an ID and just changed the colour of a cell if a particular value was found but that resulted in nothing happening when stop editing. Here is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$Text = $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('High')");
$Text.css("background-color", "green");
$Text.css("font-weight", "bold");
$Text = $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('Normal')");
$Text.css("background-color", "red");
$Text.css("font-weight", "bold");
});
</script>
```

I'm not sure of this either, but looking under what is happening I can see that the program is waiting on a GIF file and it never receives it, would this mean the post render is never called?

[image]

However, why would the alert function then run?

But I could also be way off, so was hoping someone with far more knowledge in web processes, and javascript, could help me resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specified error occurs since in **Quick Edit** mode list view is rendered differently then in default mode, that causes the following selector to return `null`:

```
var rowElementId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
var tr = document.getElementById(rowElementId);  //returns null in Quick Edit mode since tr element does not contain id attribute
```

since `tr` element does not contain `id` attribute when list view is rendered in Quick Edit mode.

Below is shown function for retrieving row element for *default & Quick Edit modes*:

```
function getTableRow(ctx,row)
{
   var rowElementId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, row);
   if(!ctx.inGridMode)
      return document.getElementById(rowElementId);
   return document.querySelectorAll('[iid="' + rowElementId +  '"]')[0];
}
```

**Final example**

Below is provided the example that demonstrates how to highlight row in List View both in default and Quick Edit modes

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {
   SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
     OnPostRender: function(ctx) {

            var colorMapping = {"High": "#F78181","Normal": "#81B1F8","Milestone": "#F3F781","Go Live": "#81B1F8"};

            var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
            for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
            {
              var key = rows[i]["Priority"];
              var color = colorMapping[key];
              highlightRow(ctx, rows[i],color);
            }            

     }
   });
});  


function highlightRow(ctx,row,color){
   var tr = getTableRow(ctx,row);
   if(tr != null)
      tr.style.backgroundColor = color;
}



function getTableRow(ctx,row)
{
   var rowElementId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, row);
   if(!ctx.inGridMode)
      return document.getElementById(rowElementId);
   return document.querySelectorAll('[iid="' + rowElementId +  '"]')[0];
}
```

> Gist: [ListView_HighlightRows.js](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/4feddc8b98d9ae85488b)

**Results**

Pic 1. List View in Quick Edit mode 
[image]

Pic 2. List View (default mode)
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your very well thought out answer!